# Can I find SDK to communicate with receipt printer by my own app on Android using Thermal or Elzab or ElzabSTX protocol?

Tags: java, android, printing, sdk, thermal-printer

I have got receipt printer and from my android app I need to print receipts, which is generated from some products I defined in android application. It's Elzab d10 printer and it has 3 protocols by wifi: Thermal, Elzab, ElzabSTX. I think that Thermal is universal and any sdk or library should already exist, but I can't find it. There is only libs for specific producents, but my producent (Elzab) gave only Wifi module (it's working) and documentation to their own protocol ElzabSTX. 
I don't want to construct whole logic and parse data to some frames of byte. Any help? Or if there is no other way, please give me some tips.

Comment: Hello did you solve your issue?

Comment: I didn't found any working sdk and I had to write logic to parse data to byte[] frames as it is described in protocol Elzab STX on producer website.